# Dimensions and file sizes of AI types (img/txt/sound) that work commercially and projections of future AI based on dimensionality and file simplicity?

Tags: data-preprocessing, data-science, dimensionality-reduction, curse-of-dimensionality

Is it accurate that current AI breakthroughs are proportional to low dimensional complexity of datasets and small data throughput?

Image and text file renders are 100's of kilobytes, and they are dimensionally very simple strings and 2D graphs.
(Phrases are ~2D permutations of words from a dictionary of 170k words, and images are 2D graphs that can easily be processed by NN vectors.)

Audio files are 2-3 megabytes and there is a Time-Frequency wave uncertainty so maths cannot analyze audio TF accurately. (voice can be simplified as graphs of vowel formants and sibilants which are 2D so it works).

Mathematics file sizes are often less than 100kb and can be represented by code, so a maths and physics GPT should be definitely a future breakthrough?

Video, 3D, mechanics, chemistry, biology, these all involve data volumes which can cause exponential strain on processing?

Can we make a linear prediction of what future Ais will happen and when simply based on their potential to factor into code and 2D formats (If so, what breakthroughs can we predict? ), with real-world audio/video/mechanics/chemistry being very, very far away?

Comment: This question isn't quite clear to me. Is your thinking "text and images are simple / low dimensional and that is why AI has worked in those domains" (?) Where simple = each observation can be represented by a small file (?).  Is "NN vectors" = nearest neighbor vectors? Also, what do you mean by "mathematics files"?

Comment: Just from experience of coding arrays for all these media, using 1d/2d/3d/4d arrays, and the data quantities involved with the processing. For 3D, scientists were heavily researching ISOsurfaces, humans rarely work with ISOsurface formulas bigger than 5kb. mathlab files, wiki maths theorems, science journal maths reasearch, are 99% file sizes less than 50kb.